# valgrind (memcheck) tool didnot detect memory-leak

Tags: c, valgrind

I introduced memory errors with following piece of C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
int i;
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
if (!a) return -1; /*malloc failed*/
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){
  a[i] = i;
}

for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){
printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i ,a[i] );
}
// free(a);
return 0;
}
```

memcheck detects the errors Invalid read/write and definitely lost, which is correct and expected.

Now, I added the same piece of code to a shared object file(.so) of my application. This application runs as a service and is a daemon process. It never exits. I applied valgrind to my application and invoked the modified '.so' .

Memcheck detects Invalid read/write errors, but not definitely lost though all these errors are in one method.can i get some help in making memcheck detect memory leak (definitely lost) error?

Thanks in advance,
PV

Comment: Are you complaining that Valgrind does not detect a memory leak in a still running application? As far as I know Valgrind cannot detect memory leaks until the process exits - in other words you will have to stop the daemon before the errors will be reported.

Answer (score 7):

How can valgrind know that you lost track of your allocated memory? It could see at the program end that the memory is not deallocated, but this is everything it can do for you. And if the program never exits, valgrind thinks you might still want to deallocate it later.

Even if valgrind would inspect all the variables and try to detect that no one points to the beginning of your allocated memory: it's perfectly legitimate to store the address in some modified form; for example, to the byte past the real beginning (think Pascal strings). So valgrind cannot detect if your code still knows about the allocated memory. Thus valgrind couldn't help you even this way.

Answer (score 0):

To actually make valgrind detect the leak, you have to affect another value to `a`.

Try adding :

```
a = NULL;
```

after your for() loop.

Now valgrind should complain!
It won't tell you that you "irremediably lost" your memory unless you **lose** track of it.

Comment: how would valgrind _know_ that the memory is really leaked?

Comment: Well, if you loose track of the *value* of the alloc'ed pointer, you *can't* recover it. Valgrind has the feature where it knows when a memory area is not pointed by any value in the program, just like a garbage collector.

Comment: not really. For example, I can unload the pointer to a file and reload it later. I can xor the pointer with a constant, in order to make stack smash less likely. I can pack several pointers tightly by removing trailing 0s (allocated pointers often have 0s at the end due to alignment). I can keep a pointer pointing to the next byte if I use the 0th byte for length (like Pascal strings do). There are thousands of valid situations where I don't have a variable in my code equal to the allocated pointer value, but I can recover the original pointer and free it.

Comment: ... that's why in particular it's impossible to implement a reasonable garbage collector in C++.

Comment: Besides that all: adding more code in order to detect an error doesn't have much sense: if we know where to add the code, than we know where the problem is, so we can fix it without valgrind. :-P

Answer (score -1):

I think that you mean

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

It would be preferable however to put a

```
#define N 10
```

or

```
const int N = 10;
```

at the beginning of your code, then to use the symbol `N` rather than the `10`.

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a memory error, which is one of the things the author is trying to detect with valgrind...